# What do (parentheses) and [square brackets] do in image prompts?

Tags: image-generation, prompt-design

I've seen a number of prompts that put parentheses or square brackets around certain words/phrases. This seems to be used across multiple frontends (Automatic1111, ComfyUI, NovelAI, ...) and regardless of model. What does this syntax do?

Comment: I think this'd do better as a "how can I adjust the weights of parts of a prompt?" question, since the syntax is a tool-specific implementation detail.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 True. Tried to capture users who've seen the syntax in-use and are unsure what it does (since it's commonly found in prompts with no explanation) - but possibly better to use your title for this post and have the syntax-specific question be separate with a brief answer (that it's used for weighting, then pointing here for details)?

Comment: I'd then close it as a duplicate of this one. (Having an upvoted answer will prevent the system from deleting the duplicate.)

Comment: See also: [Some of my important points being ignored in text-to-image generation. How to emphasize it to be in the image?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/21/10) – if you edited this question, it could be a good duplicate target for that one.

Comment: I think this is in-scope and phrased in a way that would be very beneficial to other users. I agree with @SirBenet's comment that users might see this syntax and not know that it involved weights (thus would not find a question that was specifically about adjusting weights).

Comment: The answer here only explains one of the syntaxes associated with (curly) and [square] brackets -- Attention. At the time of writing for Automatic1111, you can also get Alternating Words and Prompt Editing. I wrote [a Q&A](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/51/69) to explore all three for a forest fire.

Comment: The tag [tag:image] looks to me to be a meta tag. I suggest replacing it with the tags [tag:image-generation] and [tag:prompt-design].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Square brackets and parentheses are used for *adjusting the weight* of the contained words:

- Surrounding words with `(parentheses)` will **increase** their impact on the image,
- Surrounding words with `[square brackets]` will **decrease** their impact on the image.

You can further increase/decrease the weight by adding `(((more)))` pairs, or explicitly specify a weight value `(like this:1.2)`. Here's the same prompt/seed weighted differently:

[image: Generated images side-by-side showing how increasing weight of "red" causes the image to more prominently feature red, and vice versa]

Be aware that this is implemented per-frontend, so the specifics may differ slightly. For example, NovelAI uses `{curly brackets}` instead of parentheses, and Automatic1111 normalises weights across the prompt. Documentation:

- [Automatic1111](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Features#attentionemphasis) (also has [more advanced syntax](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/52/8) using parentheses)
- [NovelAI](https://docs.novelai.net/image/strengthening-weakening.html)
- [ComfyUI](https://github.com/comfyanonymous/ComfyUI#notes)

Comment: Is there something similar for generative language models?