# Some of my important points being ignored in text-to-image generation. How to emphasize it to be in the image?

Tags: image-generation, stable-diffusion, text-to-image, clipdrop, prompt-design

I am using [ClipDrop/Stable Diffusion](https://clipdrop.co/stable-diffusion) to generate some images with this specific prompt.

> big number 4 at the center of the image with forest in the background

and this is the result.

[image: results of big number 4 at the center of the image with forest in the background]

As you can see, my **big number 4 at the center of the image** is entirely ignored in all of the results no matter how many times I regenerate the prompt.

I tried changing the number from 4 to different numbers like 1. Still, no number comes up in the image.

How to emphasize it so that it is absolutely going to be in the image?

**Edited according to SPArcheon's suggestion:** It turns out that some styles give me the correct results. Right now, I am out of daily quotas to try more. I tried no style and anime style. With no style, it gave me the number. With anime style, it gave me like the ones in the question.

Comment: Related about prompt weight: [What do (parentheses) and [square brackets\] do in image prompts?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/1/36)

Comment: Based on a quick look at the page, you may also want to specify the style you are using. I suspect that different styles may be mapped to different models.

Comment: @SPArcheon Yes. I checked, and it turns out that some styles give me the correct results. Right now, I am out of daily quotas to try more. I tried no style and anime style. With no style, it gave me the number. With anime style, it gave me like the ones in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a blatant example of how difficult it is to have a good answer to similar issues.

As you saw firsthand the site allows you to select multiple styles but not every style works the same way. Since you are using an actual online generation service you can't even know how the thing is configured under the hood. Are the styles just prefixes that get added to the prompt you specify? Or is each style mapped to a different model file? Are they using publicly available well know model whose behavior is "documented" or do they use custom closed models?

Since all these bits of information aren't available you can only use an empirical try-and-see approach: try a prompt, see what you get, change a little, retry (**very convenient** when you are using a paid service. Imagine a pay-per-use license where it is not clear how to use said service and you have to try- and pay - again, again and again just to get how things work...).
But you already did without much luck.

Sadly this is no longer just a matter of "prompt syntax / format" but more of a "fight against the model biases" one. The model seems to be biased toward a landscape artwork and trying to insert text directly works poorly. In this case you have to test your specific use case and try to bruteforce the model into doing what you want.

I tested the site you linked as an anonymous user.

Rewriting your idea into a physical entity instead of an abstract one helps.

> (((a statue shaped like the number 4))) in the middle of an enchanted forest

[image]

Comment: It works sometimes though, like 1 image out of the generated 4 images will have a proper number statue in it like that. Better than my previous prompt anyway. Thank you!