# How do I create the start of a forest fire?

Tags: image-generation, prompt-design, stable-diffusion, text-to-image

I can create a "forest"<sup>1</sup> and a "forest fire"<sup>2</sup>. However the forest fire is extremely fiery. I'd like to have something in-between the two, preferably somewhere near the start of a fire. How can I create an image in-between the two?

1. > [image]
   > forest
   > Steps: 40, Sampler: Euler a, CFG scale: 7, Seed: 3960117709, Size: 512x512, Model hash: 06c50424
2. > [image]
   > forest fire
   > Steps: 40, Sampler: Euler a, CFG scale: 7, Seed: 3234002916, Size: 512x512, Model hash: 06c50424

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use [Alternating Words](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Features#alternating-words) to swap between generating a "forest" and a "forest fire". Doing so gives 50/50 results. Some are really smoky with some burnt foliage, good for a post fire image. Where 2 of the others have the aesthetic we'd want.

> forest[ fire| ]
> Steps: 40, Sampler: Euler a, CFG scale: 7, Seed: 1415663713, Size: 512x512, Model hash: 06c50424
> [image]

We can lower the [Attention](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Features#attentionemphasis) to give SD more room to add other information to the picture. As a result the fire seems to have a higher chance to stay in the image, and is generally smaller.

> (forest[ | fire]:0.9)
> Steps: 40, Sampler: Euler a, CFG scale: 7, Seed: 3956886801, Size: 512x512, Model hash: 06c50424
> [image]

We can see SD is struggling a bit to keep a bit of the fire in. So we can give the image a little helping hand by adding a second "forest fire" with very low attention. We can also use [Prompt Editing](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Features#prompt-editing) to not include the helping hand towards the final parts of the image creation, allowing us to not overdo the fire. If you remove the Prompt Editing we get very fiery pictures.

> (forest[ | fire]:0.9) ([forest fire::0.1]:0.1)
> Steps: 40, Sampler: Euler a, CFG scale: 7, Seed: 1168734065, Size: 512x512, Model hash: 06c50424
> [image]

The results are quite nice. We can see we're getting the fire lines from "forest fire". And the fire in the last image has been changed to a red floor.

We can instead use [Composable Diffusion](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Features#composable-diffusion) to get a similar effect. We can also see the output has the same fire lines.

> forest[ | fire] :0.9 AND forest fire :0.1
> Steps: 40, Sampler: Euler a, CFG scale: 7, Seed: 3280008852, Size: 512x512, Model hash: 06c50424
> [image]

To remove the fire lines patterns we can use a different fire type such as "bush fire" as the helper. However SD does find the different fire type harder to latch on to.

> (forest[ | fire]:0.9) ([bush fire::0.1]:0.1)
> Steps: 40, Sampler: Euler a, CFG scale: 7, Seed: 2942485071, Size: 512x512, Model hash: 06c50424
> [image]

> forest[ | fire] :0.9 AND bush fire :0.1
> Steps: 40, Sampler: Euler a, CFG scale: 7, Seed: 693952999, Size: 512x512, Model hash: 06c50424
> [image]

---

When writing the answer I messed up the syntax for a command. And rather than getting nonsense, I got, what I think are, some of the best fires of all the generated images. So even though you can help guide SD to get the output you want. Sometimes writing some absolute nonsense will get you what you want, and will look better than your best efforts. Or you could get unlucky and get the bottom three fires, which look terrible.

> (forest[ fire| ]:forest fire:0.1)
> Steps: 40, Sampler: Euler a, CFG scale: 7, Seed: 1996274752, Size: 512x512, Model hash: 06c50424
> [image]

Answer (score 4):

"Forest fire" implies the (whole) forest is burning. What you want is a small fire that happens to be in a forest:

Prompt: "small fire in a forest":

[image]