# How do users create these dense-keyword prompts for leonardo.ai?

Tags: image-generation, prompt-design, leonardo.ai

I recently used [leonardo.ai](https://app.leonardo.ai/) (freemium) for the first time.  I tried it out with my own prompts; some looked okay, but others not so much, and then I ran out of my daily tokens.  I then browsed some lovely images, like the following (click to enlarge):

> [image: girl with medium-length red hair wearing casual clothes, alone on a colorful urban street, smiling; it is a sunny day]

This is so much better than anything I came up with.  I noticed the prompt for this image is ultra specific:

> Prompt details:
>
> > (((best quality))),(((ultra detailed))),(((masterpiece))),illustration, Woman, lively, energetic, cheerful, radiant smile, captivating, youthful, graceful, slender maiden, tall and upright, charming, fresh and unique, fashionable, colorful, short hair, jeans, canvas shoes, letter prints, chain bags, bohemian, street, city, sunlight, inspiration, vitality, hope, sunny and soft, refreshing, Van Gogh
>
> Negative Prompt:
>
> > EasyNegative disfigured, bad anatomy, futa, sketches, paintings, multiple nipples, (worst quality:2), (low quality:2), (normal quality:2), low res, normal quality, ((monochrome)), ((grayscale)), dark and unclear, unclear objects, bad weather, blurry, bad contrast, poor lighting, unnatural colors, unnatural shadows, unnatural reflections, overexposed, underexposed, noisy, bad composition, poor framing, empty, uninteresting, chaotic, litter, unnatural facial features, unnatural body features, unnatural attire, unrealistic beauty standards, unnatural post-processing, excessive makeup, unrealistic retouching, unnatural pose.

It doesn't use human language, but rather a dense list of keywords along with [brackets](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/1/26).

**Question**: How do users create these dense-keyword prompts for leonardo.ai?

I could imagine someone asking ChatGPT or something to write them, or I could imagine a lot of trial and error.  Or maybe they just copy each another.

Comment: I don't know how leonardo is set up, but be careful since most of the time those "prompt sharing" site forget one small, innocent thing.... That the OP used a Lora file...

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with leonardo.ai, but have experience with MidJourney.

Try using a "prompt crafter" or "prompt builder", which itself is a ChatGPT prompt to help you write image prompts. Eg

- https://word.studio/tool/midjourney-prompt-builder/