# Why AUTOMATIC1111 is named like this?

Tags: stable-diffusion, automatic1111-sd-web-ui

Why [AUTOMATIC1111](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) is named like this?

Well, I can guess the "AUTOMATIC" part means that it *automatically* generates content for you, but what about "1111"?

I would like to know the meaning of the name, or why it came up this way.

I searched though a bunch of websites including its own official git repo, but couldn't find any information related to the name.

I will be really appreciated if the answer includes reference(s) instead of guessing.

Comment: The name of the program is “Stable Diffusion web UI”, as shown in the README. Is your question about the name of the author? https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111

Comment: The question is why is the software called AUTOMATIC1111; the answer is because the author's github username is AUTOMATIC1111.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones : The "software" is not called `AUTOMATIC1111`. The name of the software is "Stable Diffusion web UI" (source the Readme.md shown below the list of first-level files and folders). Please take a look at my [answer](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/225/12).

Comment: I thought it was called AUTOMATIC1111, but it is clear now that it is the name of the author. I don't know if this question should be closed/deleted but I am going to leave it open for future visitors that might misunderstand it like I did and this question will make it clear to them.

Comment: Since the question already has one answer with upvotes, it can't be deleted by the OP; it might be deleted by users with the delete privilege and by community  (diamond) moderators. Regarding if this should be closed, it's hard to tell, as the site scope is still being discussed.

Comment: @Wicket I know.  I made that comment when making an edit; I was explaining why editing the question to "Why AUTOMATIC1111, who created Stable Diffusion web UI, is named like this?" is incorrect.  I'm not sure what happened to my edits, but I added in three links to people referring to the *software* as AUTOMATIC1111.  This is why it's worth asking.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Awh! That is a shame that those edits aren't in the question history...  probably b/c a glitch in saving time.

Comment: The issue may be due to the fact that some people call the software *automatic1111*, sometimes without mentioning *stable diffusion* https://www.google.com/search?q=AUTOMATIC1111

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: *AUTOMATIC1111* is a **username**, not a software name. Still, many people post on the Web using it to refer to application software or other similar stuff, and some other users use this name together with the name of the corresponding item, application software, GitHub repository, etc.

---

The URL of the link included in the question is `https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui`. This URL points to a GitHub repository.

- github.com is the GitHub domain.
- The part between the slashes (`/`) after the GithHub domain, is the username or organization name; in this case, `AUTOMATIC1111` is a username.
- The part after the second slash (`/`), `stable-diffusion-webui`, is the repository name.
- Snapshot of Automatic1111's user profile page at GitHub
  [image: Automatic1111 GitHub user profile]

  <sup>Source: https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111. Taken: August 13, 2023</sup>
- *Automatic1111* has 37 repositories on GitHub. As shown in the above image, several are related to Stable Diffusion.

---

For those unfamiliar with GitHub, this is one of the most famous spaces to share code using `git`, "a distributed version control system that tracks changes in any set of computer files, usually used for coordinating work among programmers" ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git.

Among other things, GitHub allows people, most of them software developers, to share their open-source software development projects publicly. One of the GitHub characteristics that make it popular among non-experienced developers and non-developers is the possibility to use it without knowing about git, thanks to it's web user interface.

---

Reference

- [About remote repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories)

---

There is a similar question in Reddit: [Who is Automatic1111?](https://www.reddit.com/r/StableDiffusion/comments/xtyonp/who_is_automatic1111/). The current top answer points to a Discord Server and mentions that `Automatic1111` is a real person who is using this as display name and user name on Discord.

> level 1 KhaiNguyen·[10 mo. ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/StableDiffusion/comments/xtyonp/comment/iqspemt/)
> It's a real person, 1 person, you can find AUTOMATIC1111 in the Stable Diffusion official [Discord](https://discord.gg/stablediffusion) under the same name. The AUTOMATIC1111 [SD WebUI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) project is run by the same person; the project has contributions from various other developers too.

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple: the program was named after the original author.

Shortly after the Stable Diffusion model was released, several similarly-named web UIs for Stable Diffusion were released. People got in the habit of calling this one *AUTOMATIC1111* to distinguish it from the others, so although it may not be the name bestowed by the author, **it still is a name for the software**.

See [the first commit in the repository](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/commit/71cf18b012857b2cbbc52ff66f63db83689b6bfc).

Comment: +1 This is the right answer. I guess the downvotes are because it could be worded better. The author just chose AUTOMATIC1111 as their GitHub nickname, probably without thinking much. On GitHub, projects URLs automatically contain the author (or organization)'s name, and somehow "AUTOMATIC1111" is much more memorable than "stable-diffusion-webui", so I guess people got confused and the name stuck.

Comment: The commit shows that *AUTOMATIC1111* created the *Stable Diffusion web UI* project. Saying *“the program was named after the original author”* in this answer is misleading.

Comment: @A.L, shortly after the Stable Diffusion model was released, there were a bunch of similarly-named web UIs for it floating around.  People got in the habit of calling this one "AUTOMATIC1111" to distinguish it from the others, so although it may not be the name bestowed by the author, it still is *a* name for the software.

Comment: @Mark it even happened on this website, see [this answer](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/2/1103).