# How can I get leonardo.ai to draw a kite (bird) and not a kite (toy)?

Tags: prompt-design, leonardo.ai

This is a [kite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(bird)):

> [image: a black kite (image reused from Wikipedia); a bird of prey soaring in a blue sky]

Since "kite" is more commonly used to refer to the light-weight toy flown in the sky, I can't think of how to ask leonardo.ai to draw a kite (the bird).  It seems hard (or maybe even impossible) to disambiguate the two.

**Question**: How can I get leonardo.ai to draw a kite (bird) and not a kite (toy)?

I tried `kite (bird)` but it interpreted (bird) using [the bracket syntax](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/1/26).  I tried `(kite bird)`, but it drew a kite (toy) in the shape of a multi-winged gull, with visible strings:

> [image: leonardo.ai-generated image for (kite bird); a gull-shaped kite flying in the sky; we see the strings]

Comment: You could try "white tailed kite" or "black tailed kite", the common names for those birds.

Comment: @rcgldr: I gave it a try, and [that works too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nGW5.jpg)!  Perhaps it should be an answer?

Comment: I added that as an answer. There's an area in Orange County known as Kite Hill, and it's is named for the white tailed kites found in that area.

Comment: You need to figure out what tags the type of content you want has in the model you're using. You could do trial and error, but it's a lot easier to use something like CLIP Interrogator to explore what the model thinks the prompts are for an exemplar image. You will be surprised at the number of prompts that are seemingly unrelated to the subject.

Comment: Have you tried asking Leonardo.ai to draw a hawk, and then add qualifying adjectives to correct for the differences between hawks and kites (smaller tail, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this to work using the binomial name of the bird, which is *Milvus migran*. This name can be found on the [Wikipedia page about kites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(bird)).

Here's a prompt that seemed to work for me:

> Milvus migran, black kite

Along with the negative prompt:

> kites, string

[image: Generated Kite]

Comment: Binomial names are probably a pretty good choice for birds in general: there are huge numbers of bird-identification photos floating around, so it's quite likely that the training data includes a number of binomial-labeled pictures -- possibly even outnumbering the ones labeled with a common name.

Answer (score 1):

A common term would be white tailed kite or black tailed kite.

Kites are able to hover:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQbKCfnnl0I

So can the larger Ospreys which also dive into water:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhMryDlgYTI